# Mocking static methods with Robolectric and PowerMockito

Tags: android, mockito, robolectric, powermock, android-testing

I'm implementing tests with Roboelectric and I'm trying to implement a test that must check that a static method has or has not been called. My test looks like that:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@Config(manifest=Config.NONE)
@PrepareForTest({DeviceUtils.class})
@SmallTest
public class ContactsListPresenterTest extends BasePresenterTest {    
    ...

    @Test
    public void onCallContactClicked_nullArgument_methodNotCalled() {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(DeviceUtils.class);
        presenter.onCallNotaryClicked(context, null);
        PowerMockito.verifyStatic(Mockito.never());
        DeviceUtils.dialPhoneNumber(context, Mockito.anyString());
    }
    @Test
    public void onCallContactClicked_nullArgument_methodCalled() {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(DeviceUtils.class);
        presenter.onCallNotaryClicked(context, new Contact());
        PowerMockito.verifyStatic(Mockito.times(1));
        DeviceUtils.dialPhoneNumber(context, Mockito.anyString());
    }
}
```

However the test is failing with the following error:

```
org.powermock.api.mockito.ClassNotPreparedException: 
The class x.DeviceUtils not prepared for test.
To prepare this class, add class to the '@PrepareForTest' annotation.
In case if you don't use this annotation, add the annotation on class or  method level.
```

What am I doing wrong? I have already add the @PrepareForTest annotation, I guess that this is all because I'm using RobolectricTestRunner instead of PowerMockitoRunner, but I need RoboelectricTestRunner for others tests in this same class.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Are you using the `PowerMockRule`? as mentioned in the Robolectric docs

Comment: If I add the @Rule public PowerMockRule rule = new PowerMockRule(); then all tests in the class fails with: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.powermock.classloading.DeepCloner